# Number of connected components in a graph with n vertices and n-k edges

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose that we have a graph G with n vertices and n-k edges, such that it does not include any cycles. How many components does it have?

I am coming up with k components but am having a hard time proving it. Please help.

Comment: I'm guessing you know about the case of a *tree* (connected and no cycles) on $n$ vertices, having $n-1$ edges.  Can you work backward from there?

Comment: Idea/possible intuition: If we add an edge to a graph with $n$ nodes in a way such that it does not create a cycle, we have reduced the number of connected components by $1$.  Starting from $n$ connected components (one from each node) and repeating this $n-k$ times gives us $k$ components.

Answer (score 3):

If there are no cycles, $G$ is a collection of trees.  Do you know a relationship between the vertices and edges in a single tree?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a number of components, but don't know how many. Each component is connected and acyclic, which means each component is a tree. And so by tree properties, each component has $n_{i}$ nodes and $n_{i} - 1$ edges. So if we have $n$ nodes in the graph, we have:

$\sum_{i} n_{i} = n$ and $\sum_{i} (n_{i} - 1) = n - k$. It follows that 
$$\sum_{i} (n_{i} - 1) = \sum_{i} n_{i} - \sum_{i} 1 = n - \sum_{i} 1 = n - k$$

And so $\sum_{i} 1 = k$, which implies $k$ components.